# Corner detection of an image in Camera

Tags: ios, swift, document-imaging

I am very new to iOS Programming and currently trying iOS new programming language - Swift, to see what libraries are available and so forth. Currently, I am trying to create a new project in xcode 6 that takes a picture of a document. But what I want is to do the corner detection. Then user can make corners larger and smaller (depending on a user) then he/she can crop that image. For example, office lens app.

I did few researches but couple developers suggested to use GPUImage. Is it compatible with iOS8? Any other tools or easier configurations available that can help me to what I needs to get?

Are there any other libraries out there that can work with xcode6.1 or later with iOS8? I do not know much about any 3rd party libraries or examples out there that can pin-point me to right direction regarding how can I do corner detection?

Any tips/suggestions will be great, so I can learn and get better with this piece. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image feature detection is actually pretty difficult stuff. You might want to take a look at a library called OpenCV. It's a C based API that's built on top of OpenGL.  It's a pretty advanced framework that's doing advanced image processing, so unless you're a fairly senior software developer it may be over your head.

GPU image may also work for you. Yes absolutely it works under iOS. It's written in Objective-C but it should be callable from swift as well

The good news is that corner detection should be a pretty straightforward problem. That doesn't mean easy, just straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @Duncan C, I will research more on OpenCV. I am not a senior software developer yet but wants to open my options to know more about what is available out there and how can we customize.